# Closed unit ball of positive bounded operator space and its extreme point

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be  infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Then the closed unit ball of positive bounded operator space  $B(H)^+$ is not the convex hull of the projections of $B(H)$. 
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify things. You want the convex hull and not the *closed* convex hull, right?

Comment: @BerrickFillmore: yes

Comment: @BerrickFillmore: What's your suggestion?

Comment: By the Krein-Milman Theorem, $ \Bbb{B}(B(\mathcal{H})^{+}) $ is the *closed* convex hull of the projections of $ B(\mathcal{H}) $, so your problem amounts to showing that the algebraic convex hull isn’t enough to exhaust $ \Bbb{B}(B(\mathcal{H})^{+}) $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Many thanks to Martin for bringing to my attention a flaw in my earlier argument.

Here is an entirely new argument. In what follows, $ n \in \Bbb{N} $ and $ [n] \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \Bbb{N}_{\leq n} $.

- Let $ P_{1},\ldots,P_{n} $ be projections in $ B(\mathcal{H}) $. Let $ \lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{n} \in \Bbb{R}_{> 0} $ satisfy $ \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \lambda_{i} \leq 1 $.
- We claim that if $ \displaystyle T \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \lambda_{k} P_{k} $ is compact, then it has finite rank.
- Observe that $ \lambda_{k} P_{k} \leq T $ for each $ k \in [n] $.
- This implies that $ \text{Range}(P_{k}) \subseteq \text{Range}(\sqrt{T}) $ for each $ k \in [n] $.
- If $ T $ is compact, then $ \sqrt{T} $ is too, and so $ P_{k} $ has finite rank for each $ k \in [n] $.
- Hence, $ T $ also has finite rank.
- Therefore, any positive compact operator with infinite rank and norm $ \leq 1 $ cannot lie in the convex hull of the projections of $ B(\mathcal{H}) $.

Comment: @Berrick: your argument contradicts the result of Fong-Murphy (JOT 1985), where they prove that any positive contraction $T$ with $\sigma_{\rm ess}(T)\cap(0,1)\ne\emptyset$ is an average of projections. In particular, by their result, the $M_f$ you mention is an average of projections.

Comment: @Martin: Hi Martin. Let me review my answer and I’ll get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: @Martin: Hi Martin. I’ve spotted my error. My mistake can be explained as follows. If $ V $ and $ W $ are closed linear subspaces of $ \mathcal{H} $, then it isn’t necessarily true that $ V = (V \cap W) \oplus (V \cap W^{\perp}) $. Although every $ v \in V $ can be written as $ v' + v'' $, where $ v' \in W $ and $ v'' \in W^{\perp} $, it isn’t guaranteed that $ v' \in V $ or $ v'' \in V $. I’ll modify my answer in light of your reference. Thanks!

Comment: @niki: Hi Niki. I just revised my argument. Hope it sits well with you now. :)

Comment: Nice argument. $ $

Comment: Excellent, it's so nice.